# How to fix sound lag Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, audio, lag

Good night.

For some reason, when i am listening to music in Windows Media Player, and browsing something, i have a huge lag in the sound, and the page that is loading in the browsing freezes for some seconds.

How can i try to fix this problem? I verified all drivers, if they are updated, but it stays allways with the same lag.

As graphic card i have a Saphire Radeon X700 SE, and soundcard is a Creative Sound Blaster Audigy.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by 'browsing something' you mean online, probably your LAN driver is really lousy and throwing lots of DPC activity which can cause audio stuttering.  This may just be something you have to deal with based on your exact PC specifications - note that the NEWEST driver may not be the BEST in this case, though - try uninstalling it and using the default Windows one.

You can use [DPC Latency Checker](http://www.thesycon.de/deu/latency_check.shtml) and try disabling devices one at a time in Device Manager to see if you can find what specifically is causing the spikes.

Comment: Were you able to pin this one down?